# Mongodb time series query

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm new to MongoDB coming from a relational world. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have a list of patients with the following attributes:

```
    {"id": 101,
    "demographics": {"sex": "male","dob": "1/1/1984"},
    "hospital_visits": [
        {   "date": "1/1/2012",
            "diagnosis": ["diabetes","fractured hip"]
        },
        {   "date": "3/1/2012",
            "treatment": ["hip replacement"],
            "outcome": "normal discharge"
        },
        {   "date": "5/1/2012",
            "diagnosis": ["hip infection"],
            "outcome": "inpatient admission"
        }
      ]
  },
  {"id": 102,
   "hospital_visits": [
        {   "date": "1/1/2013",
            "diagnosis": ["fractured hip"]
        },
        {   "date": "3/1/2013",
            "treatment": ["hip replacement"],
            "outcome": "normal discharge"
        }
     ]
  }
```

Now, if I want to find out the number of patients that had a "fractured hip" as a diagnosis at some point (in one of the hospital visits), had a "hip replacement" treatment done subsequently at a later date (not in the same hospital visit), and within 3 months from the day of "hip replacement" treatment had an "inpatient admission" as an outcome, how do I frame my MongoDB query? Going by this logic, in the given example data, clearly patient 101 is a hit while patient 102 is not, so the count is 1. But just how do I formulate this query in MongoDB? Any ideas? Would it be easier if I change the document structure to address this question?

Many thanks!

Comment: While it might be possible using the MongoDB Aggregation framework, it's certainly not something it was designed for (especially the part about "3 months from the day").

Comment: this is exactly the sort of thing aggregation framework was designed for.  Question for OP - are you really storing dates as strings in this MM/DD/YYYY format?  I don't suppose you considered actually storing it as a Date or ISODate type?

Comment: If the treatment was done the same day as diagnosis, would it be listed in the same date subdocument or would it be a separate subdocument but listing the same date?

Answer (score 0):

One option can be:

If these queries are in considerable in number, then, whenever you update the document check for the condition that you want, and then store a suitable variable ( say some Boolean ) and you can index that variable.
The count will return very fast in that case.

Comment: thanks for the comment.  I'd consider this part of the `Roll up` flow - at least in our products (YMMV) we've always stored this a separate collection, versus inserting additional metadata into some records/documents.  I'm hoping to avoid this, because this "trivial" result size "skip" seems implementable in the db directly